# Fail to login To my developer edition Account, verification code not send by saleforce

Tags: community

Recently i came across 1 issue while trying to login in to sales-force. After i enter username and password and click on login , it take me to one verification page, where it showing , it will send 1 verification code to my registered phone Number. But unfortunately sales-force didn't send any kind of verification code to my phone.I tried "Resend code option",but it doesn't work.Its being 2 days and i am facing this issue. I am not able to login.

Please Help me to overcome this problem. If anyone, who came across this same problem kindly suggest your all possible Answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

salesforce will send verification code to email id. we have same security setup in our reales account so when ever i try to login from another system or i change my internet connection also it will ask for the verification code. that code will email to administrator. check the registered email id.

Comment: i check my Email, but verification code only going to send to my mobile number.I am not able to login,  how can i change this option(Mobile Number -> Email)

Comment: that u will get option where u added mobile number verification. but still u can't do that if u can't login to your account. in this case raise a case to salesforce about the your login problem.

Comment: Ya that is the only Option left. Hey can you tell me whats the best Approach to contact /raise issue to sales-force. Actually I am new to sales-force.

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/form/contact/contactme.jsp?d=70130000000EeYa&internal=true send your issue here may be this will help you.

Comment: Yr welcome @archita patnaik